# ¿Cómo hacer que las imágenes se muestren verticalmente cuando se llegue a cierto breakpoint en Flexbox?

Tags: html5, bootstrap, css3

Tengo un `<div>` con `flex-direction: column;` en el que se muestran imágenes en el. Sin embargo cuando se empieza a acortar el ancho de la pantalla llega un momento que el ancho de las imágenes empieza a acortarse y verse mal.

¿Existe alguna manera para aplicar en css o bien en bootstrap (es lo que estoy usando), para que una vez que el ancho de la pantalla se empiece a acortar se impida que se reduzca el ancho de la imagen, y en vez de eso hacer que empiezen a aparecer en la siguiente fila?

```css
.showcase-container img{
   width: 120px;
   height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <main>
      <div class="showcase-container d-flex flex-row">
       <div><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/05/Monumental_Plaza_de_Espa%C3%B1a_de_Sevilla.jpg/240px-Monumental_Plaza_de_Espa%C3%B1a_de_Sevilla.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image"></div>
      <div><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/df/Plaza_Virgen_de_los_Reyes%2C_Seville%2C_Spain_-_Sep_2009.jpg/250px-Plaza_Virgen_de_los_Reyes%2C_Seville%2C_Spain_-_Sep_2009.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image"></div>
       <div><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/05/Monumental_Plaza_de_Espa%C3%B1a_de_Sevilla.jpg/240px-Monumental_Plaza_de_Espa%C3%B1a_de_Sevilla.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image"></div>
       
      <div><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/df/Plaza_Virgen_de_los_Reyes%2C_Seville%2C_Spain_-_Sep_2009.jpg/250px-Plaza_Virgen_de_los_Reyes%2C_Seville%2C_Spain_-_Sep_2009.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image"></div>
       
     <div><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/05/Monumental_Plaza_de_Espa%C3%B1a_de_Sevilla.jpg/240px-Monumental_Plaza_de_Espa%C3%B1a_de_Sevilla.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image"></div>
        <div><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/df/Plaza_Virgen_de_los_Reyes%2C_Seville%2C_Spain_-_Sep_2009.jpg/250px-Plaza_Virgen_de_los_Reyes%2C_Seville%2C_Spain_-_Sep_2009.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image"></div>
      </div>
      
      
    </div>
  </main>
```

¿Se puede hacer con flexbox o sería más apropiado usar CSS Grid?

Comment: Lo más apropiado sería usar Media Query, con esto le dices que cuando llegue a cierrta medida haga lo que tu le indiques dentro.

Comment: Entiendo, el problema es que con Media Query tendría que asumir manualmente y dependiendo de la anchura de la pantalla del usuario quizás me confunda. Sin embargo si pudiese indicarselo con el auto-responsive de bootstrap sería exacto.

Answer (score 0):

De momento he encontrado esta solución con CSS Grid que me sirve usando `auto-fit`, la dejo aquí pero si alguien sabe una solución sin tener que usar Css Grid bienvenido sea

```css
.showcase-container{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(100px, 1fr));

}
```